# Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required on laravel 5 ( windows 10 )

Tags: laravel-5, windows-10

While using laravel 5 when I try to start the server `php artisan serve` or any "artisan command", I receive this error message:

> Warning: require(C:\Users\Djebi\OneDrive\Desktop\Nom-de-projet/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in artisan on line 18
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\Users\Djebi\OneDrive\Desktop\Nom-de-projet/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in artisan on line 18

[image]

Answer (score 2):

composer update --no-scripts

Run this line on cmd or bash from your laravel project folder then try again. It's work for me. Normally it happens when you work on a clone project.